# Transaction timedout after 300s Websphere , Spring batch, DB2

Tags: transactions, db2, websphere

I have a need to execute 5000 select statements on a datasource and pull results and insert the 5000 values to table of a different data source.

for 5000 select statements(all are different sqls) I am exeuting one by one
(This is taking more time)

for 5000 inserts I am doing JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate()

The above job needs to be executed for every 30mins. I have configured spring batch to do this job which will be triggered for every 30 mins by CRON.

Once the method is called to complete 5000 select statements It's taking more than 300s to complete So the Websphere is throwing timeout exception. It says Global transaction time exceeded 300s.

I know I can increase the timeout in websphere but I can't do that since in production the server profiles are configured default.

Can someone suggest me a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase your transaction timeout on the current thread using

```
transaction.setTransactionTimeout(int seconds)
```

on your `UserTransaction` before calling

```
transaction.begin()
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try reducing the number of SELECTs as requests and responses for each of them are separate items of network latency, regardless how much time they take on the database side. Issuing 5000 individual queries and waiting for their individual results does take time even if the queries are simple `SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`s

If two or more queries have the same type of results, then you can join them with `UNION`s and if two or more queries are expected to have the same number of results, then you can join them through their result columns or a made-up key like one generated with ROW_NUMBER():

`select a,b,c from ....  and select a,e,f from...` turns into

```
select table1.a, b,c,d,e,f from
table (select a,b,c from ...) table1,
table (select a,e,f from ...) table2
where
 table1.a = table2.a
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks marks and Turan yuksel for your suggestions. I have resolved the problem.

I have splitted the 5000 sqls to smaller units and processing as a list of requests instead of a request with 5000 sqls. Now there is no timeout problem with the spring batch. The timeout caused by the Spring batch item writer, since the batch transaction was timed out after 300 seconds.

Now It's resolved. Hope this helps for someone who is facing similar problems.